# Which gem is breaking Rails application.css.scss wrong number of arguments 3 for 2

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Okay.  This is a new problem caused by a gem update.  Calling bundle update breaks my rails application.  Here are the gems that changed:

```
# Gemfile.lock
-    compass (0.12.7)
+    compass (0.12.2)
-      sass (~> 3.2.19)
+      sass (~> 3.1)
-    country_select (2.0.1) # Not likely this
+    country_select (2.1.0) # Not likely this
-    devise (3.3.0)
+    devise (3.4.0)
+      responders
-    excon (0.39.6)
-    execjs (2.2.1)
+    excon (0.40.0)
+    execjs (2.2.2)
-    jbuilder (2.1.3)
+    jbuilder (2.2.2)
-    jquery-ui-rails (5.0.0)
+    jquery-ui-rails (5.0.1)
-    mime-types (2.3)
+    mime-types (2.4.2)
-    netrc (0.7.7)
+    netrc (0.8.0)
-    omniauth-twitter (1.0.1) # Not likely this
+    omniauth-twitter (1.1.0) # Not likely this
-    railroady (1.1.2)  # Not likely this
+    railroady (1.2.0) # Not likely this
-    rails_12factor (0.0.2)
+    rails_12factor (0.0.3)
-    rails_layout (1.0.22)
+    rails_layout (1.0.23)
-    sass (3.2.19)
+    sass (3.2.0)
-    sprockets-rails (2.1.4)
+    sprockets-rails (2.2.0)
-      sprockets (~> 2.8)
+      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
-    turbolinks (2.3.0)
+    turbolinks (2.4.0)
-    twilio-ruby (3.13.0) # Not likely this
+    twilio-ruby (3.13.1) # Not likely this
```

The error I get is:

```
wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)
(in /app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scss)
```

And better errors shows it happening at this line:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

If you can tell me which gem is responsible for the error I can version out the new one in my Gemfile.  It does the same thing on my local machine and Heroku.  I'm maintaining the older **Gemfile.lock** for now.

---

For the record I tried installing each gem individually.  Afterwards I had no problem on the local machine, but Heroku failed with the same error and would not build.

---

Following Paul Richter's tip it's either compass, sprockets, or sass

```
sass-rails (4.0.3) lib/sass/rails/importer.rb:80:in `engine_from_path'
sass-rails (4.0.3) lib/sass/rails/importer.rb:27:in `find_relative'
sass (3.2.0) lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:45:in `import'
sass (3.2.0) lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:25:in `imported_file'
sass (3.2.0) lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:34:in `css_import?'
sass (3.2.0) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:214:in `visit_import'
sass (3.2.0) lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
sass (3.2.0) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:97:in `visit'
sass (3.2.0) lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `block in visit_children'
sass (3.2.0) lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `visit_children'
sass (3.2.0) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:106:in `block in visit_children'
sass (3.2.0) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:118:in `with_environment'
sass (3.2.0) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:105:in `visit_children'
sass (3.2.0) lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `block in visit'
sass (3.2.0) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:125:in `visit_root'
sass (3.2.0) lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
sass (3.2.0) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:97:in `visit'
sass (3.2.0) lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:7:in `visit'
sass (3.2.0) lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'
sass (3.2.0) lib/sass/engine.rb:315:in `_render'
sass (3.2.0) lib/sass/engine.rb:262:in `render'
compass-rails (2.0.0) lib/compass-rails/patches/sass_importer.rb:29:in `evaluate'
tilt (1.4.1) lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/context.rb:197:in `block in evaluate'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `evaluate'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:12:in `initialize'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `block in build_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:395:in `circular_call_protection'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:373:in `build_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `build_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/environment.rb:75:in `find_asset'
sprockets (2.11.0) lib/sprockets/base.rb:295:in `[]'
sprockets-rails (2.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:230:in `lookup_asset_for_path'
sprockets-rails (2.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:190:in `check_errors_for'
sprockets-rails (2.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:159:in `block in stylesheet_link_tag'
sprockets-rails (2.2.0) lib/sprockets/rails/helper.rb:158:in `stylesheet_link_tag'
```

Comment: On the error page, there is a link that says "Full Trace". Open that up, and look up and down that and see if you can determine where its originally failing (ie the specific method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found that the updated gems, which have in their instructions to change **application.css** to **application.css.scss**, don't recognize just **'application'** as a parameter for a **scss** file for **stylesheet_link_tag**.  You need to change:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

to this:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'application.css.scss', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
```

This will allow you to work with the latest gems.

Answer (score 14):

The problem is with `sass`. Here's a link to the the [official issue](https://github.com/rails/sass-rails/issues/85).

Locking `sass-rails` to version 4.0.3 has worked for me on rails-4.0.x through rails-4.1.x. In your Gemfile:

```
gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.3'
```

UPDATE

A better solution I have found is to use the `4-0-stable` branch:

```
gem 'sass-rails', github: 'rails/sass-rails', branch: '4-0-stable'
```

Comment: Adding `gem 'sass', '3.2.19'` fixed it.

Answer (score 6):

I believe this is actually a problem with sass and compass dependencies.
I had the same issue in Rails 4.1.5.
The default Gemfile includes:

```
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
```

But a simple bundle update within the last month (Oct/Nov 2014) breaks the application.
I was able to fix it by adding the following lines to my Gemfile to preserve the dependencies between compass and sass:

```
gem 'sass', '~> 3.2.19'
gem 'compass', '~> 0.12.7'
gem 'compass-rails', '~> 2.0.0'
```

**Update Dec 2014:**

I ran into this same issue again after trying to upgrade to Zurb Foundation 5.5.
It seems like the main culprit is the compass-rails gem.  Even after I pulled out the gem, I found that a different gem I was using (chosen-rails) was pulling it back in.
After getting rid of all the sass and compass lines (and chosen-rails), the following works for me:

```
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.0'
gem 'foundation-rails', '~> 5.5'
```

Comment: Hi @TwiceB - I also have the problem but can't get it to work - getting different errors such as the 3 for 2 or Sprockets::FileNotFound error. Would you post your full Gemfile please?

Comment: Thanks very much, @TwiceB. Unfortunately didn't help. I get a `Sprockets::FileNotFound at /dashboard
couldn't find file '(NOT IMPORTED) /Users/rasmus/.rbenv/versions/2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/foundation-rails-5.5.0.0/vendor/assets/stylesheets/foundation/_functions.scss'`error. If you have any ideas why that could be, any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Got it! See my answer below :)  Thanks for helping out, @TwiceB! :)

Answer (score 6):

`bundle update sass` did the trick.

Comment: Thanks man, i spent so much time with this error, however this command worked for me.

Comment: No problem, love to share.

Answer (score 3):

I fixed this problem with:

```
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.2'
gem 'sass', '3.2.19'
gem 'sprockets', '2.11.0'
gem 'sprockets-rails', '2.0.1'
gem 'compass-rails', '~> 2.0'
```

Answer (score 2):

For solving it, I remove Gem using compass-rails.

In my case I was using chosen-rails, replacing it with select2, now all work fine with 'rails', '4.2.0' and 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.0'

Answer (score 1):

Removing compass from my gemfile (remember `bundle install`) and then using the new sprockets beta fixed it for me.

`gem "sprockets", "~>3.0.0.beta"` in gemfile. Then `bundle update sprockets`.

Enjoy :)