# Alchemy CMS Issue on Initial Load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, alchemy-cms

I 'successfully' installed Alchemy but when I navigate to the admin page for the first time I get:

```
ArgumentError in Alchemy::Users#new


wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)
  (in /Users/bar/Developer/Websites/testsite/.bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bundler/gems/alchemy_cms-702202acd197/app/assets/stylesheets/alchemy/admin.css.scss)


   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/alchemy/favicon.ico">
   <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
   <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag('alchemy/admin', :media => 'screen', "data-turbolinks-track" => true) %>
   <%= stylesheet_link_tag('alchemy/print', :media => 'print', "data-turbolinks-track" => true) %>
   <%= yield :stylesheets %>
   <script>
```

What did I do wrong or not do?  Is this an error in the 'stable' release?  (Hope not otherwise I will throw a seemingly great CMS out the window...)

Edit:

Installed Alchemy using the standalone new project method.

Using alchemy-devise for user auth.

GEMFILE

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.6'
# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',        group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',      group: :development

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]


gem "alchemy_cms", github: "magiclabs/alchemy_cms", branch: "master"
gem "alchemy-devise", github: "magiclabs/alchemy-devise", branch: "master"
gem "capistrano", "~> 2.15.5", group: "development"
```

GEMFILE.lock

```
GIT
  remote: git://github.com/magiclabs/alchemy-devise.git
  revision: 9db0c896bc9b9de2c064bcf0a34b6391e6937d58
  branch: master
  specs:
    alchemy-devise (2.0.0)
      alchemy_cms (~> 3.0.0)
      devise (~> 3.0.0)

GIT
  remote: git://github.com/magiclabs/alchemy_cms.git
  revision: b712ac2fc9fdc3cb6786b1c6733f8d37be4c2588
  branch: master
  specs:
    alchemy_cms (3.0.2)
      actionpack-page_caching (~> 1.0.0)
      active_model_serializers (>= 0.8.1, < 0.10.0)
      acts-as-taggable-on (~> 3.1)
      acts_as_list (~> 0.3.0)
      awesome_nested_set (~> 3.0.0.rc.2)
      cancan (~> 1.6.10)
      coffee-rails (~> 4.0.0)
      compass-rails (>= 1.1.2)
      dragonfly (~> 1.0.1)
      jquery-rails (~> 3.1.0)
      jquery-ui-rails (~> 5.0.0)
      kaminari (~> 0.15)
      magiclabs-userstamp (~> 2.1.0)
      non-stupid-digest-assets (~> 1.0.3)
      rails (>= 4.0, < 5.0)
      request_store (~> 1.1.0)
      sass-rails (>= 4.0.2)
      sassy-buttons (~> 0.2.6)
      select2-rails (~> 3.4)
      simple_form (~> 3.0.1)
      spinner.rb
      turbolinks (~> 2.0)
      tvdeyen-handles_sortable_columns (~> 0.1.5)
      uglifier (>= 1.3.0)

GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actionmailer (4.1.6)
      actionpack (= 4.1.6)
      actionview (= 4.1.6)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
    actionpack (4.1.6)
      actionview (= 4.1.6)
      activesupport (= 4.1.6)
      rack (~> 1.5.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.2)
    actionpack-page_caching (1.0.2)
      actionpack (>= 4.0.0, < 5)
    actionview (4.1.6)
      activesupport (= 4.1.6)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
    active_model_serializers (0.9.0)
      activemodel (>= 3.2)
    activemodel (4.1.6)
      activesupport (= 4.1.6)
      builder (~> 3.1)
    activerecord (4.1.6)
      activemodel (= 4.1.6)
      activesupport (= 4.1.6)
      arel (~> 5.0.0)
    activesupport (4.1.6)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.9)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    acts-as-taggable-on (3.4.2)
      activerecord (>= 3.2, < 5)
    acts_as_list (0.3.0)
      activerecord (>= 3.0)
    addressable (2.3.6)
    arel (5.0.1.20140414130214)
    awesome_nested_set (3.0.1)
      activerecord (>= 4.0.0, < 5)
    bcrypt (3.1.9)
    bcrypt-ruby (3.1.5)
      bcrypt (>= 3.1.3)
    builder (3.2.2)
    cancan (1.6.10)
    capistrano (2.15.5)
      highline
      net-scp (>= 1.0.0)
      net-sftp (>= 2.0.0)
      net-ssh (>= 2.0.14)
      net-ssh-gateway (>= 1.1.0)
    chunky_png (1.3.3)
    coffee-rails (4.0.1)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
    coffee-script (2.3.0)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.8.0)
    compass (0.12.2)
      chunky_png (~> 1.2)
      fssm (>= 0.2.7)
      sass (~> 3.1)
    compass-rails (2.0.0)
      compass (>= 0.12.2)
    devise (3.0.4)
      bcrypt-ruby (~> 3.0)
      orm_adapter (~> 0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.6, < 5)
      warden (~> 1.2.3)
    dragonfly (1.0.7)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.2.2)
    fssm (0.2.10)
    highline (1.6.21)
    hike (1.2.3)
    i18n (0.6.11)
    jbuilder (2.2.4)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0, < 5)
      multi_json (~> 1.2)
    jquery-rails (3.1.2)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-ui-rails (5.0.2)
      railties (>= 3.2.16)
    json (1.8.1)
    kaminari (0.16.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    magiclabs-userstamp (2.1.0)
    mail (2.6.1)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 3)
    mime-types (2.4.3)
    minitest (5.4.2)
    multi_json (1.10.1)
    mysql2 (0.3.16)
    net-scp (1.2.1)
      net-ssh (>= 2.6.5)
    net-sftp (2.1.2)
      net-ssh (>= 2.6.5)
    net-ssh (2.9.1)
    net-ssh-gateway (1.2.0)
      net-ssh (>= 2.6.5)
    non-stupid-digest-assets (1.0.4)
    orm_adapter (0.5.0)
    rack (1.5.2)
    rack-test (0.6.2)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (4.1.6)
      actionmailer (= 4.1.6)
      actionpack (= 4.1.6)
      actionview (= 4.1.6)
      activemodel (= 4.1.6)
      activerecord (= 4.1.6)
      activesupport (= 4.1.6)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0)
      railties (= 4.1.6)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
    railties (4.1.6)
      actionpack (= 4.1.6)
      activesupport (= 4.1.6)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (10.3.2)
    rdoc (4.1.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    request_store (1.1.0)
    sass (3.2.0)
    sass-rails (4.0.3)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 5.0)
      sass (~> 3.2.0)
      sprockets (~> 2.8, <= 2.11.0)
      sprockets-rails (~> 2.0)
    sassy-buttons (0.2.6)
      compass (>= 0.12.2)
    sdoc (0.4.1)
      json (~> 1.7, >= 1.7.7)
      rdoc (~> 4.0)
    select2-rails (3.5.9.1)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    simple_form (3.0.2)
      actionpack (~> 4.0)
      activemodel (~> 4.0)
    spinner.rb (0.3.0)
    spring (1.1.3)
    sprockets (2.11.0)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sprockets-rails (2.2.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
    thor (0.19.1)
    thread_safe (0.3.4)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    turbolinks (2.5.1)
      coffee-rails
    tvdeyen-handles_sortable_columns (0.1.5)
    tzinfo (1.2.2)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    uglifier (2.5.3)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0)
      json (>= 1.8.0)
    warden (1.2.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  alchemy-devise!
  alchemy_cms!
  capistrano (~> 2.15.5)
  jbuilder (~> 2.0)
  mysql2
  rails (= 4.1.6)
  sass-rails (~> 4.0.3)
  sdoc (~> 0.4.0)
  spring
  uglifier (>= 1.3.0)
```

Comment: Can you please provide some informations about how you have installed alchemy - and which gems are used in your application.

Comment: Seems like a problem with the Assets Pipeline of Rails and is not particular Alchemy related. Could you please paste your `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`, Thanks.

Comment: @tvdeyen The requested files were posted.

Comment: I used exactly the same gem stack to setup a fresh new app with alchemy, but I did not get any issues. How did you setup your app, what were the steps you did?

Comment: @robin you need to use the alchemy executable to create a new project. I did and got the same issue. BAR please open an issue at the GitHub tracker. Thanks.

Comment: Will do. I have to say this experience is exactly what I am afraid of in an immature CMS.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, I opened https://github.com/magiclabs/alchemy_cms/issues/656

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26416065/which-gem-is-breaking-rails-application-css-scss-wrong-number-of-arguments-3-for