# heroku push rejected failed to compile Ruby app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

heroku push rejected failed to compile Ruby app

heres my code why its not working please help i spend the whole day on it

gem file

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.1.8'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc
gem 'spring',        group: :development

group :development do
  gem "interactive_editor"
  gem "hirb"
  gem "awesome_print"
  gem 'byebug'
end

gem "rails_12factor"
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~>3.2.0'

gem 'compass-rails'

gem "animate-rails"
gem 'rails_log_stdout',           github: 'heroku/rails_log_stdout'
gem 'rails3_serve_static_assets', github: 'heroku/rails3_serve_static_assets'

group :production do
  gem 'thin'  
end

group :test, :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

when i put git push heroku master

```
    Counting objects: 183, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (167/167), done.
Writing objects: 100% (183/183), 956.75 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 183 (delta 54), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Removing .DS_Store files
remote: -----> Ruby app detected
remote: -----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
remote: -----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.0.0
remote: -----> Installing dependencies using 1.9.7
remote:        Running: bundle install --without development:test --path vendor/bundle --binstubs vendor/bundle/bin -j4 --deployment
remote:        Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
remote:        Fetching version metadata from https://rubygems.org/...
remote:        Fetching dependency metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
remote:        Fetching git://github.com/heroku/rails3_serve_static_assets.git
remote:        Fetching git://github.com/heroku/rails_log_stdout.git
remote:        Rubygems 2.0.14 is not threadsafe, so your gems must be installed one at a time. Upgrade to Rubygems 2.1.0 or higher to enable parallel gem installation.
remote:        Installing rake 10.4.2
remote:        Installing i18n 0.7.0
remote:        Installing json 1.8.3
remote:        Installing minitest 5.7.0
remote:        Installing thread_safe 0.3.5
remote:        Installing tzinfo 1.2.2
remote:        Installing activesupport 4.1.8
remote:        Installing builder 3.2.2
remote:        Installing erubis 2.7.0
remote:        Installing actionview 4.1.8
remote:        Installing rack 1.5.4
remote:        Installing rack-test 0.6.3
remote:        Installing actionpack 4.1.8
remote:        Installing mime-types 2.6.1
remote:        Installing mail 2.6.3
remote:        Installing actionmailer 4.1.8
remote:        Installing activemodel 4.1.8
remote:        Installing arel 5.0.1.20140414130214
remote:        Installing activerecord 4.1.8
remote:        Using bundler 1.9.7
remote:        Installing thor 0.19.1
remote:        Installing railties 4.1.8
remote:        Installing hike 1.2.3
remote:        Installing multi_json 1.11.1
remote:        Installing tilt 1.4.1
remote:        Installing sprockets 2.11.0
remote:        Installing sprockets-rails 2.3.1
remote:        Installing rails 4.1.8
remote:        Installing animate-rails 1.0.8
remote:        Installing sass 3.2.0
remote:        Installing bootstrap-sass 3.2.0.2
remote:        Installing chunky_png 1.3.4
remote:        Installing coffee-script-source 1.9.1.1
remote:        Installing execjs 2.5.2
remote:        Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
remote:        Installing coffee-rails 4.0.1
remote:        Installing fssm 0.2.10
remote:        Installing compass 0.12.2
remote:        Installing compass-rails 2.0.0
remote:        Installing daemons 1.2.2
remote:        Installing eventmachine 1.0.7
remote:        Installing jbuilder 2.3.0
remote:        Installing jquery-rails 3.1.3
remote:        Installing pg 0.18.2
remote:        Using rails3_serve_static_assets 0.0.1 from git://github.com/heroku/rails3_serve_static_assets.git (at master)
remote:        Installing rails_serve_static_assets 0.0.4
remote:        Installing rails_stdout_logging 0.0.3
remote:        Installing rails_12factor 0.0.3
remote:        Using rails_log_stdout 0.0.1 from git://github.com/heroku/rails_log_stdout.git (at master)
remote:        Installing rdoc 4.2.0
remote:        Installing sass-rails 4.0.3
remote:        Installing sdoc 0.4.1
remote:        Installing thin 1.6.3
remote:        Installing turbolinks 2.5.3
remote:        Installing uglifier 2.7.1
remote:        Bundle complete! 22 Gemfile dependencies, 55 gems now installed.
remote:        Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
remote:        Bundled gems are installed into ./vendor/bundle.
remote:        Post-install message from rdoc:
remote:        Depending on your version of ruby, you may need to install ruby rdoc/ri data:
remote:        <= 1.8.6 : unsupported
remote:        = 1.8.7 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
remote:        = 1.9.1 : gem install rdoc-data; rdoc-data --install
remote:        >= 1.9.2 : nothing to do! Yay!
remote:        Bundle completed (91.69s)
remote:        Cleaning up the bundler cache.
remote: -----> Preparing app for Rails asset pipeline
remote:        Running: rake assets:precompile
remote:        I, [2015-06-16T23:45:18.654868 #995]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/public/assets/about-img-b9ffcdc5dbcaf14d02ba4da8a51e16de.jpg
remote:        I, [2015-06-16T23:45:18.657482 #995]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/public/assets/client_logo1-f60fdf8601b400482240ba15987052f2.png
remote:        I, [2015-06-16T23:45:18.659602 #995]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/public/assets/client_logo2-5d31c470fe3c5fc4375acd974ea017b3.png
remote:        I, [2015-06-16T23:45:18.661911 #995]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/public/assets/client_logo3-71d18b824e166043f06220dc5b3869f3.png
remote:        I, [2015-06-16T23:45:18.664169 #995]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/public/assets/client_logo4-e5a0a65672a466106706f4d3d3595c73.png
remote:        I, [2015-06-16T23:45:18.666333 #995]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/public/assets/client_logo5-37553648e07af3d0d140efb9d747b215.png
remote:        I, [2015-06-16T23:45:18.668445 #995]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/public/assets/logo-7028972b9819c7cb22b75852d8228127.png
remote:        I, [2015-06-16T23:45:18.670928 #995]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/public/assets/main_device_image-d00f490caaa7897d4fa337a65049f24e.png
remote:        I, [2015-06-16T23:45:18.673392 #995]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/public/assets/portfolio_pic1-1b116177a910bd2948fd867b00a7f680.jpg
remote:        I, [2015-06-16T23:45:18.675587 #995]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/public/assets/portfolio_pic2-0a575a1420a6dea896ff9ec7ab465eac.jpg
remote:        I, [2015-06-16T23:45:18.678345 #995]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/public/assets/portfolio_pic3-379efb3bae8baa74ffc35eccd22ab026.jpg
remote:        I, [2015-06-16T23:45:18.680612 #995]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/public/assets/portfolio_pic4-5c73d9b8fc7bf24c980d1e96472dfa7b.jpg
remote:        I, [2015-06-16T23:45:18.683032 #995]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/public/assets/portfolio_pic5-1a09b66d3a7688dfd1bbd2c2f58c0699.jpg
remote:        I, [2015-06-16T23:45:18.685502 #995]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/public/assets/portfolio_pic6-738f93240d99deee8e6fd63e98468245.jpg
remote:        I, [2015-06-16T23:45:18.687864 #995]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/public/assets/portfolio_pic7-0b8633bdf00db4d09a02fa0714e2230c.jpg
remote:        I, [2015-06-16T23:45:18.690523 #995]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/public/assets/portfolio_pic8-75990f1d6efe11d862c3ec599cfbe664.jpg
remote:        I, [2015-06-16T23:45:18.692731 #995]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/public/assets/team_pic1-8b292aa638afadc831c66895d6887158.jpg
remote:        I, [2015-06-16T23:45:18.694899 #995]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/public/assets/team_pic2-a89aa048a515f2aef80f2f93265b86f4.jpg
remote:        I, [2015-06-16T23:45:18.697225 #995]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/public/assets/team_pic3-b544d99fdc6b2c6bbcfefb810e3f36d3.jpg
remote:        I, [2015-06-16T23:45:18.703280 #995]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/public/assets/twitter_bird-1e64e0bfe6393a56f76ac189e25e7b4f.png
remote:        I, [2015-06-16T23:45:26.018610 #995]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/public/assets/application-1cac7178e74e0c5d1600dbfb79d4e8c9.js
remote:        rake aborted!
remote:        ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (3 for 2)
remote:        (in /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss)
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.0/lib/sass/importers/filesystem.rb:109:in `find_real_file'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass/rails/importer.rb:80:in `engine_from_path'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-rails-4.0.3/lib/sass/rails/importer.rb:27:in `find_relative'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.0/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:45:in `import'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.0/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:25:in `imported_file'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.0/lib/sass/tree/import_node.rb:34:in `css_import?'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:214:in `visit_import'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:97:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `block in visit_children'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `map'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:53:in `visit_children'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:106:in `block in visit_children'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:118:in `with_environment'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:105:in `visit_children'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `block in visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:125:in `visit_root'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:37:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:97:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.0/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:7:in `visit'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.0/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.0/lib/sass/engine.rb:315:in `_render'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sass-3.2.0/lib/sass/engine.rb:262:in `render'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/compass-rails-2.0.0/lib/compass-rails/patches/sass_importer.rb:29:in `evaluate'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:197:in `block in evaluate'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `evaluate'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:12:in `initialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `new'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `block in build_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:395:in `circular_call_protection'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:373:in `build_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:111:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:105:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:105:in `resolve_dependencies'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:97:in `build_required_assets'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `new'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `block in build_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:395:in `circular_call_protection'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:373:in `build_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `new'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `build_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:211:in `block in find_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:257:in `benchmark'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:210:in `find_asset'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:119:in `block in compile'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `each'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `compile'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:70:in `block (3 levels) in define
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-2.11.0/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:146:in `with_logger'
remote:        /tmp/build_f081972916d04442370a144719bac013/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.3.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:69:in `block (2 levels) in define
remote:        Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
remote:        (See full trace by running task with --trace)
remote:  !
remote:  !     Precompiling assets failed.
remote:  !
remote: 
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
remote: 
remote: Verifying deploy....
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to seamless-bridge-ltd.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/seamless-bridge-ltd.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/seamless-bridge-ltd.git'
```

what should i do , i tried many time to add and remove gems to work but its not

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which gem is breaking Rails application.css.scss wrong number of arguments 3 for 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26416065/which-gem-is-breaking-rails-application-css-scss-wrong-number-of-arguments-3-for)

Comment: show your `/app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.scss`

Answer (score 0):

put this line in your application.rb

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```